# enabling i386 arch on amd64 Debian Buster and installing libc6:i386 tries to replace the entire os

Tags: debian, x86, multiarch

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
```

I'd like to install `libc6:i386` to support an old proprietary printer driver.  I've performed the following:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt update
```

When I attempt to install `libc6:i386` via

```
apt install libc6:i386
```

I am presented with a message indicating that most of the existing packages, including essential packages will be removed.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

[ seemingly all of the automatically installed packages on my system]

Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-10-base:i386 libcrypt1:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libunistring2:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 debconf:i386 | debconf-2.0:i386 locales:i386
Recommended packages:
  libnss-nis:i386 libnss-nisplus:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:

[ seemingly all of remaining packages, including X, etc ]

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-10-base:i386 libc6:i386 libcrypt1:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libidn2-0:i386 libunistring2:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt adduser (due to apt) gpgv (due to apt) libapt-pkg6.0 (due to apt) libc6 (due to apt) libgcc-s1 (due to apt) libgnutls30 (due to apt) libseccomp2 (due to apt)
  libstdc++6 (due to apt) libsystemd0 (due to apt) base-files base-passwd libdebconfclient0 (due to base-passwd) bash libtinfo6 (due to bash) debianutils (due to bash) bsdutils
  coreutils libacl1 (due to coreutils) libattr1 (due to coreutils) libgmp10 (due to coreutils) libselinux1 (due to coreutils) dash dpkg (due to dash) debconf (due to dash)
  diffutils libbz2-1.0 (due to dpkg) liblzma5 (due to dpkg) zlib1g (due to dpkg) tar (due to dpkg) e2fsprogs libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libcom-err2 (due to e2fsprogs)
  libext2fs2 (due to e2fsprogs) libss2 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (due to e2fsprogs) logsave (due to e2fsprogs) findutils grep libpcre3 (due to grep) install-info (due to grep)
  gzip hostname init systemd-sysv (due to init) init-system-helpers (due to init) perl-base (due to init-system-helpers) libc-bin libcrypt1 login libaudit1 (due to login)
  libpam0g (due to login) libpam-runtime (due to login) libpam-modules (due to login) ncurses-bin sed sysvinit-utils util-linux libcap-ng0 (due to util-linux)
  libmount1 (due to util-linux) libsmartcols1 (due to util-linux) libudev1 (due to util-linux)
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 2746 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,579 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.7 GB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

Here are my source repositories:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main non-free contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main non-free contrib
deb [arch=amd64] http://http.debian.net/debian bullseye-backports main non-free contrib
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
deb [arch=amd64] https://xpra.org/ bullseye main
```

Any idea on what might be causing this?

**EDIT 1:**

The system is up-to-date prior to adding the architecture, e.g.

```
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Directly after adding the new architecture and running `apt update`, an `apt upgrade` returns this:

```
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnupg gnupg-l10n
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

which seems to indicate there's already an issue prior to attempting to install `libc`

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? You need to run `apt upgrade` before trying this.

Comment: Yes, the system is up-to-date.

Comment: I've updated the OP with more information about the upgrade status.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the `[arch=amd64]` qualifier from the `bullseye-backports` line?

Comment: The presence (or absence) of the qualifier doesn't change the behavior. (TBH, I  put it in there to try and prevent i386 from upgrading things.)